# Use mfizz icons in overleaf

Tags: fonts, symbols

I want to use [fizzed](http://fizzed.com/oss/font-mfizz) icons on my overleaf page.
I [downloaded](https://www.cdnpkg.com/font-mfizz/file/font-mfizz.ttf/)  version 2.4.1 and uploaded it to overleaf.

but how can I use icons?

here my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

 \faGithub\\
 \faBootstrap\\
  \faGit\\
   \faDocker\\
   
\end{document}
```

Comment: you just need https://github.com/fizzed/font-mfizz/blob/master/dist/font-mfizz.ttf  then use fontspec package (and lualatex) to access it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you please show which code should I add the my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface\mfz{font-mfizz.ttf}

\def\setfizz#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname fizz #1\endcsname{{\mfz#2}}}
\def\usefizz#1{\csname fizz #1\endcsname}

\setfizz{3dprint}{^^^^f100}
\setfizz{alpinelinux}{^^^^f101}
\setfizz{angular}{^^^^f102}
\setfizz{angular-alt}{^^^^f103}
\setfizz{antenna}{^^^^f104}
\setfizz{apache}{^^^^f105}
\setfizz{archlinux}{^^^^f106}
\setfizz{aws}{^^^^f107}
\setfizz{azure}{^^^^f108}
\setfizz{backbone}{^^^^f109}
\setfizz{blackberry}{^^^^f10a}
\setfizz{bomb}{^^^^f10b}
\setfizz{bootstrap}{^^^^f10c}
\setfizz{c}{^^^^f10d}
\setfizz{cassandra}{^^^^f10e}
\setfizz{centos}{^^^^f10f}
\setfizz{clojure}{^^^^f110}
\setfizz{codeigniter}{^^^^f111}
\setfizz{codepen}{^^^^f112}
\setfizz{coffee-bean}{^^^^f113}
\setfizz{cplusplus}{^^^^f114}
\setfizz{csharp}{^^^^f115}
\setfizz{css}{^^^^f116}
\setfizz{css3}{^^^^f117}
\setfizz{css3-alt}{^^^^f118}
\setfizz{d3}{^^^^f119}
\setfizz{database}{^^^^f11a}
\setfizz{database-alt}{^^^^f11b}
\setfizz{database-alt2}{^^^^f11c}
\setfizz{debian}{^^^^f11d}
\setfizz{docker}{^^^^f11e}
\setfizz{dreamhost}{^^^^f11f}
\setfizz{elixir}{^^^^f120}
\setfizz{elm}{^^^^f121}
\setfizz{erlang}{^^^^f122}
\setfizz{exherbo}{^^^^f123}
\setfizz{fedora}{^^^^f124}
\setfizz{fire-alt}{^^^^f125}
\setfizz{freebsd}{^^^^f126}
\setfizz{freecodecamp}{^^^^f127}
\setfizz{gentoo}{^^^^f128}
\setfizz{ghost}{^^^^f129}
\setfizz{git}{^^^^f12a}
\setfizz{gnome}{^^^^f12b}
\setfizz{go}{^^^^f12c}
\setfizz{go-alt}{^^^^f12d}
\setfizz{google}{^^^^f12e}
\setfizz{google-alt}{^^^^f12f}
\setfizz{google-code}{^^^^f130}
\setfizz{google-developers}{^^^^f131}
\setfizz{gradle}{^^^^f132}
\setfizz{grails}{^^^^f133}
\setfizz{grails-alt}{^^^^f134}
\setfizz{grunt}{^^^^f135}
\setfizz{gulp}{^^^^f136}
\setfizz{gulp-alt}{^^^^f137}
\setfizz{hadoop}{^^^^f138}
\setfizz{haskell}{^^^^f139}
\setfizz{heroku}{^^^^f13a}
\setfizz{html}{^^^^f13b}
\setfizz{html5}{^^^^f13c}
\setfizz{html5-alt}{^^^^f13d}
\setfizz{iphone}{^^^^f13e}
\setfizz{java}{^^^^f13f}
\setfizz{java-bold}{^^^^f140}
\setfizz{java-duke}{^^^^f141}
\setfizz{javascript}{^^^^f142}
\setfizz{javascript-alt}{^^^^f143}
\setfizz{jetty}{^^^^f144}
\setfizz{jquery}{^^^^f145}
\setfizz{kde}{^^^^f146}
\setfizz{laravel}{^^^^f147}
\setfizz{line-graph}{^^^^f148}
\setfizz{linux-mint}{^^^^f149}
\setfizz{looking}{^^^^f14a}
\setfizz{magento}{^^^^f14b}
\setfizz{mariadb}{^^^^f14c}
\setfizz{maven}{^^^^f14d}
\setfizz{microscope}{^^^^f14e}
\setfizz{mobile-device}{^^^^f14f}
\setfizz{mobile-phone-alt}{^^^^f150}
\setfizz{mobile-phone-broadcast}{^^^^f151}
\setfizz{mongodb}{^^^^f152}
\setfizz{mssql}{^^^^f153}
\setfizz{mysql}{^^^^f154}
\setfizz{mysql-alt}{^^^^f155}
\setfizz{netbsd}{^^^^f156}
\setfizz{nginx}{^^^^f157}
\setfizz{nginx-alt}{^^^^f158}
\setfizz{nginx-alt2}{^^^^f159}
\setfizz{nodejs}{^^^^f15a}
\setfizz{npm}{^^^^f15b}
\setfizz{objc}{^^^^f15c}
\setfizz{openshift}{^^^^f15d}
\setfizz{oracle}{^^^^f15e}
\setfizz{oracle-alt}{^^^^f15f}
\setfizz{osx}{^^^^f160}
\setfizz{perl}{^^^^f161}
\setfizz{phone-alt}{^^^^f162}
\setfizz{phone-gap}{^^^^f163}
\setfizz{phone-retro}{^^^^f164}
\setfizz{php}{^^^^f165}
\setfizz{php-alt}{^^^^f166}
\setfizz{playframework}{^^^^f167}
\setfizz{playframework-alt}{^^^^f168}
\setfizz{plone}{^^^^f169}
\setfizz{postgres}{^^^^f16a}
\setfizz{postgres-alt}{^^^^f16b}
\setfizz{python}{^^^^f16c}
\setfizz{raspberrypi}{^^^^f16d}
\setfizz{reactjs}{^^^^f16e}
\setfizz{redhat}{^^^^f16f}
\setfizz{redis}{^^^^f170}
\setfizz{ruby}{^^^^f171}
\setfizz{ruby-on-rails}{^^^^f172}
\setfizz{ruby-on-rails-alt}{^^^^f173}
\setfizz{rust}{^^^^f174}
\setfizz{sass}{^^^^f175}
\setfizz{satellite}{^^^^f176}
\setfizz{scala}{^^^^f177}
\setfizz{scala-alt}{^^^^f178}
\setfizz{script}{^^^^f179}
\setfizz{script-alt}{^^^^f17a}
\setfizz{shell}{^^^^f17b}
\setfizz{sitefinity}{^^^^f17c}
\setfizz{solaris}{^^^^f17d}
\setfizz{splatter}{^^^^f17e}
\setfizz{spring}{^^^^f17f}
\setfizz{suse}{^^^^f180}
\setfizz{svg}{^^^^f181}
\setfizz{symfony}{^^^^f182}
\setfizz{tomcat}{^^^^f183}
\setfizz{ubuntu}{^^^^f184}
\setfizz{unity}{^^^^f185}
\setfizz{wireless}{^^^^f186}
\setfizz{wordpress}{^^^^f187}
\setfizz{x11}{^^^^f188}

\begin{document}


\usefizz{python} + \usefizz{x11}

{\Huge \usefizz{python} + \usefizz{x11}}

\end{document}
```